# Python vending machine error (order coffees is not defined)

Tags: python, list, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I want to categorize the food by category, set the category, and choose the food. I want the total price to rise after choosing food. The order coffee part is a problem for me. Coffee menus overlap with other categories. Also, if I press the order completed button, I want a receipt with a thank you message. What should I do?

My error message is

```
The menu you entered does not exist.
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/mason/PycharmProjects/APCSP/APCSP.py", line 174, in <lambda>
    btn_drink_1 = tk.Button(frame3, text="Iced Coffee\n($2.65)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: drink_add('Iced Coffee'))
  File "/Users/mason/PycharmProjects/APCSP/APCSP.py", line 60, in drink_add
    total_price += this_price
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

Here is my code

```
price_meal = {"Donut": 1.25, "Filled Donut": 1.50, "Apple Fritter": 2.95, "Cinnamon roll": 2.95, "Muffin": 2.95, "Scone": 2.95}
price_drink = {"Hot Tea": 1.95, "Hot Chocolate": 1.75, "Milk": 1.50, "Chocolate Milk": 1.95, "Soda": 2.25}
price_coffees = {"Iced Coffee": 2.65, "Cold Brew": 3.95, "Iced Americano" :2.45, "Mochatella":4.25, "Iced Mochatella": 4.75, "Cafe Caramel/Mocha": 4.70}

order_meal = {}
order_drink = {}
order_coffees = {}

total_price = 0


def show_meal():
    btn_meal.configure(bg="yellow")
    btn_drink.configure(bg="white")
    frame4.pack_forget()
    frame3.pack_forget()
    frame2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    frame4.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

def show_drink():
    btn_meal.configure(bg="white")
    btn_drink.configure(bg="yellow")
    frame4.pack_forget()
    frame2.pack_forget()
    frame3.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    frame4.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

def show_coffees():
    btn_meal.configure(bg="white")
    btn_drink.configure(bg="yellow")
    frame4.pack_forget()
    frame2.pack_forget()
    frame3.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    frame4.pack(fill="both", expand=True)


def meal_add(m):
    global price_meal, order_meal, total_price
    if m not in price_meal:
        print("The menu you entered does not exist.")
    this_price = price_meal.get(m)
    total_price += this_price

    if m in order_meal:
        order_meal[m] = order_meal.get(m) + 1
    else:
        order_meal[m] = 1
    print_order()
    print_price()


def drink_add(m):
    global price_drink, order_drink, total_price
    if m not in price_drink:
        print("The menu you entered does not exist.")
    this_price = price_drink.get(m)
    total_price += this_price

    if m in order_drink:
        order_drink[m] = order_drink.get(m) + 1
    else:
        order_drink[m] = 1
    print_order()
    print_price()


def coffees_add(m):
    global price_coffees, order_coffees, total_price
    if m not in price_coffees:
        print("The menu you entered does not exist.")
    this_price = price_coffees.get(m)
    total_price += this_price

    if m in order_coffees:
        order_drink[m] = order_coffees.get(m) + 1
    else:
        order_coffees[m] = 1
    print_order()
    print_price()


def print_order():
    global order_meal, order_drink, order_coffees

    tmp = ""
    price_tmp = 0
    for i in order_meal:
        price_tmp = price_meal[i] * order_meal.get(i)
        tmp = tmp + i + " X " + str(order_meal.get(i)) +  " = " + str(price_tmp)+"\n"
    for i in order_drink:
        price_tmp = price_drink[i] * order_drink.get(i)
        tmp = tmp + i + " X " + str(order_drink.get(i)) +  " = " + str(price_tmp)+"\n"
    for i in order_coffees:
        price_tmp = price_coffees[i] * order_coffees.get(i)
        tmp = tmp + i + " X " + str(order_coffees.get(i)) +  " = " + str(price_tmp)+"\n"

    text_1.delete('1.0', tk.END)
    text_1.insert(tk.INSERT, tmp)


def order_end():
    global total_price, order_meal, order_drink, order_coffees
    total_price = 0
    del order_meal
    del order_drink
    del order_coffees

    order_meal = {}
    order_drink = {}
    order_coffees = {}
    print_price()
    print_order()
    show_meal()


def print_price():
    global total_price
    label_price.configure(text=str(total_price))


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Brunch Cafe")
window.geometry("800x400+500+300")
window.resizable(False, False)

frame1 = tk.Frame(window, width="800", height="10")
frame1.pack(fill="both")

frame2 = tk.Frame(window, width="800")
frame2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

frame3 = tk.Frame(window, width="800")
frame3.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

frame4 = tk.Frame(window, width="800")
# frame4.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

frame5 = tk.Frame(window, width="800", height="10")
frame5.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

btn_meal = tk.Button(frame1, text="meal", padx="10", pady="10", bg="yellow", command=show_meal)
btn_meal.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_drink = tk.Button(frame1, text="drinks", padx="10", pady="10", bg="white", command=show_drink)
btn_drink.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_end = tk.Button(frame1, text="Order Completed", padx="10", pady="10", command=order_end)
btn_end.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

label_price = tk.Label(frame1, text="0 dollars", width="20", padx=10, pady="10", fg="blue", font='Arial 15')
label_price.grid(row=0, column="3", padx="10", pady="10")

# Meal
btn_meal_1 = tk.Button(frame2, text="Donut\n($1.25)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: meal_add('Donut'))
btn_meal_1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_meal_2 = tk.Button(frame2, text="Filled Donut\n($1.50)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: meal_add('Filled Donut'))
btn_meal_2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_meal_3 = tk.Button(frame2, text="Cinnamon roll\n($2.95)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: meal_add('Cinnamon roll'))
btn_meal_3.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_meal_4 = tk.Button(frame2, text="Muffin\n($2.95)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: meal_add('Muffin'))
btn_meal_4.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_meal_5 = tk.Button(frame2, text="Scone\n($2.95)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: meal_add('Scone'))
btn_meal_5.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)


# Coffees
btn_drink_1 = tk.Button(frame3, text="Iced Coffee\n($2.65)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: drink_add('Iced Coffee'))
btn_drink_1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_drink_2 = tk.Button(frame3, text="Cold Brew\n($3.95)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: drink_add('Cold Brew'))
btn_drink_2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_drink_3 = tk.Button(frame3, text="Iced Americano\n($2.45)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: drink_add('Iced Americano'))
btn_drink_3.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_drink_4 = tk.Button(frame3, text="Mochatella\n($4.25)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: drink_add('Mochatella'))
btn_drink_4.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_drink_6 = tk.Button(frame3, text="Iced Mochatella\n($4.75)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: drink_add('Iced Mochatella'))
btn_drink_6.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_drink_7 = tk.Button(frame3, text="Cafe Caramel/Mocha\n($4.70)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: drink_add('Cafe Caramel/Mocha'))
btn_drink_7.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)


# Drinks
btn_drink_1 = tk.Button(frame4, text="Hot Tea\n($1.95)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: drink_add('Hot Tea'))
btn_drink_1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_drink_2 = tk.Button(frame4, text="Hot Chocolate\n($1.75)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: drink_add('Hot Chocolate'))
btn_drink_2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_drink_3 = tk.Button(frame4, text="Milk\n($1.50)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: drink_add('Milk'))
btn_drink_3.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_drink_4 = tk.Button(frame4, text="Soda\n($2.25)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: drink_add('Soda'))
btn_drink_4.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)


# Order list
text_1 = tk.Text(frame5, height="10")
text_1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error happens.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: You have called `drink_add()` for all coffees. Should use `coffees_add()` instead.

Comment: That's telling yo that `this_price` is `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have used `drink_add()` for all coffee items. Use `coffees_add()` instead:

```py
# Coffees
btn_drink_1 = tk.Button(frame3, text="Iced Coffee\n($2.65)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: coffees_add('Iced Coffee'))
btn_drink_1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_drink_2 = tk.Button(frame3, text="Cold Brew\n($3.95)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: coffees_add('Cold Brew'))
btn_drink_2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_drink_3 = tk.Button(frame3, text="Iced Americano\n($2.45)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: coffees_add('Iced Americano'))
btn_drink_3.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_drink_4 = tk.Button(frame3, text="Mochatella\n($4.25)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: coffees_add('Mochatella'))
btn_drink_4.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_drink_6 = tk.Button(frame3, text="Iced Mochatella\n($4.75)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: coffees_add('Iced Mochatella'))
btn_drink_6.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_drink_7 = tk.Button(frame3, text="Cafe Caramel\n/Mocha\n($4.70)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: coffees_add('Cafe Caramel/Mocha'))
btn_drink_7.grid(row=0, column=5, padx=10, pady=10)
```

Note that I have also changed `column=4` to `column=5` for `btn_drink_7`.  Also you have used same set of variable names for `coffees` and `drinks`.

---

There is typo in the following block inside `coffees_add()`:

```
if m in order_coffees:
    order_drink[m] = order_coffees.get(m) + 1   # <- order_coffees[m] should be used instead
else:
    order_coffees[m] = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How can I change the variable of coffee and drinks?

Comment: You can change those `btn_drink_x` for coffee items to `btn_coffee_x`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem. The problem seems to be with the `.get()` function, not with the `btn` variables at all.

Comment: @10Rep Did you really read my description? The cause is using `drink_add()` instead of `coffees_add()` for coffee items so the selected coffee item cannot be found in `price_drink` dictionary.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't seem to be what's actually causing the error. The error is caused by using the .get() method for dictionaries. It returns a None value if you don't put a value as a parameter, which is what the OP did. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @10Rep Please read carefully on OP code.  Which line in OP code has called `get()` without argument?

Comment: `get()` required two arguments, the `key`, and the `value`. So if you do `dictionary.get(m)`, you will get None because it requires two parameters. The OP's code has this line: `this_price = price_coffees.get(m)`. That is the culprit.

Comment: @10Rep Where do you learn that `.get()` on dictionary requires exactly two argument? The second argument is optional.

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/get says that `.get()` will return None if the key is not found, or if the value is not specified.

Comment: @10Rep As I said, the second argument is *optional*.  It is returned if the key cannot be found in the dictionary.  Also I have said that OP used `drink_add()` for coffee items, so it cannot find the coffee item in `price_drink`.  If OP changes to `coffees_add()`, then such error is fixed.

Comment: @MasonMount As I notice that you have used my suggestion in your new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67595285/python-vending-machine-making-new-page), so accept my answer if it solves this question.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that `this_price` is a `None`. Why would that be so?

Well, if we check out [the documentation](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/get) for the [`.get`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/get) method:

> `None` if the key is not found and value is not specified.

In your code, you are not passing a value to the `.get()` method. The parameters are `[key, value]`, and you did not pass value.

So, switch out the `this_price = price_meal.get(m)` with `this_price = price_meal[str(m)]`, and you will get the value, which is exactly what you want.

Instead of using `.get`, you would be using [`slice notation`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/12708583). Python will look through the dictionary for `m`, and when it finds `m`, it will return the value for `m` in the dictionary, which is the price.

Your entire code would look something like this:

```py
price_meal = {"Donut": 1.25, "Filled Donut": 1.50, "Apple Fritter": 2.95, "Cinnamon roll": 2.95, "Muffin": 2.95, "Scone": 2.95}
price_drink = {"Hot Tea": 1.95, "Hot Chocolate": 1.75, "Milk": 1.50, "Chocolate Milk": 1.95, "Soda": 2.25}
price_coffees = {"Iced Coffee": 2.65, "Cold Brew": 3.95, "Iced Americano" :2.45, "Mochatella":4.25, "Iced Mochatella": 4.75, "Cafe Caramel/Mocha": 4.70}

order_meal = {}
order_drink = {}
order_coffees = {}

total_price = 0


def show_meal():
    btn_meal.configure(bg="yellow")
    btn_drink.configure(bg="white")
    frame4.pack_forget()
    frame3.pack_forget()
    frame2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    frame4.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

def show_drink():
    btn_meal.configure(bg="white")
    btn_drink.configure(bg="yellow")
    frame4.pack_forget()
    frame2.pack_forget()
    frame3.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    frame4.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

def show_coffees():
    btn_meal.configure(bg="white")
    btn_drink.configure(bg="yellow")
    frame4.pack_forget()
    frame2.pack_forget()
    frame3.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    frame4.pack(fill="both", expand=True)


def meal_add(m):
    global price_meal, order_meal, total_price
    if m not in price_meal:
        print("The menu you entered does not exist.")
    this_price = price_meal[m]
    total_price += this_price

    if m in order_meal:
        order_meal[m] = order_meal[m] + 1
    else:
        order_meal[m] = 1
    print_order()
    print_price()


def drink_add(m):
    global price_drink, order_drink, total_price
    if m not in price_drink:
        print("The menu you entered does not exist.")
    this_price = price_drink[m]
    total_price += this_price

    if m in order_drink:
        order_drink[m] = order_drink[m] + 1
    else:
        order_drink[m] = 1
    print_order()
    print_price()


def coffees_add(m):
    global price_coffees, order_coffees, total_price
    if m not in price_coffees:
        print("The menu you entered does not exist.")
    this_price = price_coffees[m]
    total_price += this_price

    if m in order_coffees:
        order_drink[m] = order_coffees[m] + 1
    else:
        order_coffees[m] = 1
    print_order()
    print_price()


def print_order():
    global order_meal, order_drink, order_coffees

    tmp = ""
    price_tmp = 0
    for i in order_meal:
        price_tmp = price_meal[i] * order_meal[i]
        tmp = tmp + i + " X " + str(order_meal[i]) +  " = " + str(price_tmp)+"\n"
    for i in order_drink:
        price_tmp = price_drink[i] * order_drink[i]
        tmp = tmp + i + " X " + str(order_drink[i]) +  " = " + str(price_tmp)+"\n"
    for i in order_coffees:
        price_tmp = price_coffees[i] * order_coffees[i]
        tmp = tmp + i + " X " + str(order_coffees[i]) +  " = " + str(price_tmp)+"\n"

    text_1.delete('1.0', tk.END)
    text_1.insert(tk.INSERT, tmp)


def order_end():
    global total_price, order_meal, order_drink, order_coffees
    total_price = 0
    del order_meal
    del order_drink
    del order_coffees

    order_meal = {}
    order_drink = {}
    order_coffees = {}
    print_price()
    print_order()
    show_meal()


def print_price():
    global total_price
    label_price.configure(text=str(total_price))

import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Brunch Cafe")
window.geometry("800x400+500+300")
window.resizable(False, False)

frame1 = tk.Frame(window, width="800", height="10")
frame1.pack(fill="both")

frame2 = tk.Frame(window, width="800")
frame2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

frame3 = tk.Frame(window, width="800")
frame3.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

frame4 = tk.Frame(window, width="800")
# frame4.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

frame5 = tk.Frame(window, width="800", height="10")
frame5.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

btn_meal = tk.Button(frame1, text="meal", padx="10", pady="10", bg="yellow", command=show_meal)
btn_meal.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_drink = tk.Button(frame1, text="drinks", padx="10", pady="10", bg="white", command=show_drink)
btn_drink.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_end = tk.Button(frame1, text="Order Completed", padx="10", pady="10", command=order_end)
btn_end.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

label_price = tk.Label(frame1, text="0 dollars", width="20", padx=10, pady="10", fg="blue", font='Arial 15')
label_price.grid(row=0, column="3", padx="10", pady="10")

# Meal
btn_meal_1 = tk.Button(frame2, text="Donut\n($1.25)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: meal_add('Donut'))
btn_meal_1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_meal_2 = tk.Button(frame2, text="Filled Donut\n($1.50)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: meal_add('Filled Donut'))
btn_meal_2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_meal_3 = tk.Button(frame2, text="Cinnamon roll\n($2.95)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: meal_add('Cinnamon roll'))
btn_meal_3.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_meal_4 = tk.Button(frame2, text="Muffin\n($2.95)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: meal_add('Muffin'))
btn_meal_4.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_meal_5 = tk.Button(frame2, text="Scone\n($2.95)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: meal_add('Scone'))
btn_meal_5.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)


# Coffees
btn_drink_1 = tk.Button(frame3, text="Iced Coffee\n($2.65)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: drink_add('Iced Coffee'))
btn_drink_1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_drink_2 = tk.Button(frame3, text="Cold Brew\n($3.95)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: drink_add('Cold Brew'))
btn_drink_2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_drink_3 = tk.Button(frame3, text="Iced Americano\n($2.45)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: drink_add('Iced Americano'))
btn_drink_3.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_drink_4 = tk.Button(frame3, text="Mochatella\n($4.25)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: drink_add('Mochatella'))
btn_drink_4.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_drink_6 = tk.Button(frame3, text="Iced Mochatella\n($4.75)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: drink_add('Iced Mochatella'))
btn_drink_6.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_drink_7 = tk.Button(frame3, text="Cafe Caramel/Mocha\n($4.70)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: drink_add('Cafe Caramel/Mocha'))
btn_drink_7.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)


# Drinks
btn_drink_1 = tk.Button(frame4, text="Hot Tea\n($1.95)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: drink_add('Hot Tea'))
btn_drink_1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_drink_2 = tk.Button(frame4, text="Hot Chocolate\n($1.75)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: drink_add('Hot Chocolate'))
btn_drink_2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_drink_3 = tk.Button(frame4, text="Milk\n($1.50)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: drink_add('Milk'))
btn_drink_3.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

btn_drink_4 = tk.Button(frame4, text="Soda\n($2.25)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: drink_add('Soda'))
btn_drink_4.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)


# Order list
text_1 = tk.Text(frame5, height="10")
text_1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Note that I essentially replaced every instance of `dictionary.get(m)` with `dictionary[m]`.

Comment: The menu you entered does not exist.
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Use/PycharmProjects/APCSP/APCSP.py", line 178, in <lambda>
    btn_drink_3 = tk.Button(frame3, text="Iced Americano\n($2.45)", padx="10", pady="10", width="10", command=lambda: drink_add('Iced Americano'))
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/APCSP/APCSP.py", line 57, in drink_add
    this_price = price_drink[m]
KeyError: 'Iced Americano'

Comment: Thank you so much. I did what you told me and these errors came up. What should I do?

Comment: @MasonMount the reason that is app[earing is because "Iced Americano" Is not in your dictionary. You may want to add it. You may have meant to type "Iced American".

Comment: @MasonMount is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?